# Combining Futures of different types in Scala in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, parallel-processing

I have some scala code in a method that looks like :

```
def testMethod = Action {

   val future1: Future[List[A]] = methodA()
   val future2: Future[List[String]] = methodB()
   val future3: Future[List[B]] = methodC()

   Ok("Testing...")
}
```

How do I combine them together into a single future so that I can return an Async Result like:

```
def testMethod = Action {

   val future1: Future[List[A]] = methodA()
   val future2: Future[List[String]] = methodB()
   val future3: Future[List[B]] = methodC()

   val combinedFuture: Future[(List[A],List[String],List[B])] // the single Future needed

   Async {

       combinedFuture.map( item => 

           Ok("It is done...")

       )

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use For-comprehensions like this:

```
val combinedFuture: Future[(List[A],List[String],List[B])] = for{
   l1 <- future1,
   l2 <- future2,
   l3 <- future3
}yield{
   (l1, l2, l3)
}
```

You could also put your Futures in a list, which makes a list of futures, then use `Future.sequence(your list)` to get a Future of list instead of a list of futures.

Comment: I tried them, gave me an error : Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext, either import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global or use a custom one.

I imported the said package and the error subsided, but I'm not sure  if that is the right way?

Comment: And also, no errors if I import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._ instead of the scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global , what is the difference between them, would both work similarly?

Comment: The difference is that the Play one is handling the Play Actor system needed to do all sorts of Async operations. The Scala one isn't capable of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
val combinedFuture = Future.sequence(List(future1,future2,future3))
```